# CacheAsBitmap and filters

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Why is cacheAsBitmap automatically set to true when using filters?

I have a movieclip that is drawn to the stage every frame and since it has a playing timeline and it rotates every once in a while I want to have cacheAsBitmap set to false. But the movieclip has a dropshadow-filter which sets cacheAsBitmap to true, doesn't this mean that I lose a lot of performance by caching every frame?

Would removing the dropshadow-filter from the movieclip being drawn and apply it to all its children instead be a solution?

Comment: See this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001283.html#374074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Docs:

> The cacheAsBitmap property is automatically set to true whenever you
>   apply a filter to a movie clip (when its filter array is not empty).
>   If a movie clip has a filter applied to it, cacheAsBitmap is reported
>   as true for that movie clip, even if you set the property to false. If
>   you clear all filters for a movie clip, the cacheAsBitmap setting
>   changes to what it was last set to.

I believe this is because Flash Player has to use the bitmap version of your MovieClip to apply the effects - most filters are done at the pixel level. It is then cached so further transformations (like `x/y`) are more efficient. So really it doesn't really make a difference wether `cacheAsBitmap` is set to true or false.

Using filters + timeline animations is generally a bad idea. However, a good optimization would be to apply the filters deeper inside the display list, on objects that are not animated. Even better, try to use bitmap with rasterized effects if possible so your effects are not calculated at runtime.

Don't forget to use Scout to see exactly what the player does to your objects!

Comment: I can't pre-rasterize anything I think because as my movieclip rotates the shadow needs to update, the movieclip is supposed to always cast a shadow at 45 degrees, and the shadow will of course look different depending on how the movieclip is rotated.

But I will put the shadow deeper in the movieclip then, thanks a lot for the explanation and advice.